# Chisel poke() print format

Tags: scala, chisel

Is it possible to configure the print format of poke() function in Chisel test class ?

I want to 'poke()' an **unsigned** long (64bits) int and Chisel print it like a **signed** long int when I launch this code:

```
  poke(c.io.masterwrite.wdata, 0xbebecacacafedecaL)
```

The result :

```
  POKE AvlMasterWrite.io_masterwrite_wdata <-  -0x4141353535012136
```

I can't add the letter 'U' like in C to force unsigned :

```
 0xbebecacacafedecaUL
```

That doesn't compile.

Comment: See this related feature request, which has been languishing for a while: https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel/issues/178

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
import java.math._

poke (c.io.masterwrite.wdata, new BigInteger("bebecacacafedeca", 16)
```

The input port `c.io.masterwrite.wdata` should be of type `UInt` and 64-bit long.